# Gsub raises "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gsub

I have the next method call:

```
Formatting.git_log_to_html(`git log --no-merges master --pretty=full #{interval}`)
```

The value of `interval` is something like `release-20130325-01..release-20130327-04`.

The `git_log_to_html` ruby method is the next (I am only pasting the line what raises the error):

```
module Formatting
  def self.git_log_to_html(git_log)
    ...
    git_log.gsub(/^commit /, "COMMIT_STARTcommit").split("COMMIT_STARTcommit").each do |commit|
    ...
  end
end
```

This used to work, but actually I checked that gsub is raising an "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8" error.

Could you help to understand why and how can I fix it? :/

Here is the output of `git_log`:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/42306424/output.txt

Comment: Whenever I see this message, I add the line `#encoding: utf-8` to the top of the file and that's fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, this command:

```
git log --no-merges master --pretty=full #{interval}
```

is giving you a result that is not encoded in UTF-8, it may be that your computer is working with a different charset, try the following:

```
module Formatting
  def self.git_log_to_html(git_log)
    ...
    git_log.force_encoding("utf8").gsub(/^commit /, "COMMIT_STARTcommit").split("COMMIT_STARTcommit").each do |commit|
    ...
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if that will work, but you can try.

If that doesn't work, you can check ruby iconv to detect the charset and encode it on utf-8: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/

---

Based on the file you added on the comment, I did:

```
require 'open-uri'
content = open('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/42306424/output.txt').read
content.gsub(/^commit /, "COMMIT_STARTcommit").split("COMMIT_STARTcommit")
```

and worked nice without any kind of troubles

---

btw, you can try:

```
require 'iconv'

module Formatting
  def self.git_log_to_html(git_log)
    ...
    git_log = Iconv.conv 'UTF-8', 'iso8859-1', git_log
    git_log.gsub(/^commit /, "COMMIT_STARTcommit").split("COMMIT_STARTcommit").each do |commit|
    ...
  end
end
```

but you should really detect the charset of the string before attempting a conversion to utf-8.

Comment: I will try with ruby iconv (force encoding didn't worked), but if it's help, here is the output of `git log --no-merges master --pretty=full #{interval}`: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/42306424/output.txt I don't see non-utf8 characters :(

Comment: There are indeed non-utf8 characters. The file is ISO-8859-1 encoded. So for example an `á` is not going to be valid utf-8 in that file

Comment: ISO-8859-1 is supported within UTF-8, the problem is when you use an encoding that cannot be easily transformed into UTF-8, i.e.: UTF-16.

Comment: There is no problem *converting* from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, but ISO-8859-1 is not a binary subset of UTF-8, you actually have to convert it. I didn't *think* there was a problem converting from UTF-16 either? A quick Google suggests this is the case, but I've not done much with UTF-16, so not 100% certain.

Comment: Iconv really worked, and I added your solution with a conditional for checking if the encode is (or not) compatible with utf8: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Encoding.html Thank you both for the help!